# Selecting some of One where there're none of Many

Tags: ihp

I'm trying to find domains that don't have any usernames with a given name, that is free domains. Hopefully there's a solution to this that doesn't require 2 separate queries, but I also ran into a problem with type system.

```
-- error Couldn't match type 'IO [Domain]' with '[[Domain]]', points to beginning of filter

            Just term -> do
                usernames <- query @Username
                    |> filterWhere (#name, term) |> fetch >>= collectionFetchRelated #domainId
                domains <- search |> filter \x->case find (\y->get #domainId x == get #domainId y) usernames of
                    Just _ -> True
                    Nothing -> False
                render IndexView {..}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `-- error Couldn't match type 'IO [Domain]' with '[[Domain]]', points to beginning of filter` is happening because of the arrow notation here:

```hs
                domains <- search |> filter \x->case find (\y->get #domainId x == get #domainId y) usernames of
                    Just _ -> True
                    Nothing -> False
```

As this is not doing any IO, it needs to use a `let`:

```hs
                let domains = search |> filter \x->case find (\y->get #domainId x == get #domainId y) usernames of
                    Just _ -> True
                    Nothing -> False
```

Now the type of `domains` is `[[Domain]]` (a list of list of domains). Likely we want `[Domain]` (just a normal list of domains).

We can use [`concat`](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/concat_f.html) for that purpose:

```hs
                let domains = search
                        |> filter ( \x-> case find (\y->get #domainId x == get #domainId y) usernames of
                                Just _ -> True
                                 Nothing -> False
                            )
                        |> concat
```

Now the type error should be gone.

---

> Hopefully there's a solution to this that doesn't require 2 separate queries

Yes this is doable as well with a handwritten query:

```hs
domains <- sqlQuery "SELECT domains.* FROM domains WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usernames WHERE usernames.domain_id = domains.id AND usernames.name = ?) = 0" [term]
```

Comment: let domains = search is IO, and appending concat somehow made it worse to produce [[[Domains]]] after I also added brackets in front of filter. Nevertheless as far as IHP goes, this is solved.